# In Javascript, get length of matching regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, how do I get the length of the regex match?

For example, if the string is

```
str = "/abc/hellothere/andmore/"
```

And the regexp is

```
reg = new RegExp('/abc/[^/]*/');
```

Then I want 16, the length of

```
/abc/hellothere/
```

Comment: Are you sure that regex matches your string?

Comment: Yes, now. Added a "/" to front of str.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you actually want your regex to match your sample input:

```js
var str = '/abc/hellothere/andmore/';
var reg = new RegExp('/abc/[^/]*/');
var matches = str.match(reg);

if (matches && matches.length) {
  console.log(matches[0].length);
}
```

The expected output should be `16`.

Refer to [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [`RegExp.prototype.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).